# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/JSONModel.framework/JSONModel

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode7, citrus-pay

I have installed CitrusPay for my application through CocoaPod. After running my project i am getting runtime error as -

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/JSONModel.framework/JSONModel
>   Referenced from:
>   /Users/Savita/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3E53CBD1-C475-465C-ADE5-84C2248E134F/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/E8A12E93-1820-401B-B687-87D8F752F812/ProjectName.app/Frameworks/CitrusPay.framework/CitrusPay   Reason: image not found

Does anyone knows the solution please help..

Answer (score 1):

Add your CitrusPay.framework in `Embedded Binaries`.

[image]